# Binding some attributes of object to data

Tags: d3.js

I have data in the form of an object, and I'm trying to bind only some attributes of the object to my selection as data.

The object looks something like this:

```
var data = {'attr1': 100,
            'attr2': "foo",
            'attr3': 200,
            ...
            'attr20': 34}
```

I have the attribute names I'm interested in stored in an array:

```
keys = ['attr1', 'attr3', 'attr20']
```

I want to bind the values (100, 200, 34). I'm doing the following:

```
var selection = d3.select('ul')
                  .selectAll('li')
                  .data(keys, function(key){ return data[key]})
                  .enter()
                  .append('li')
                  .text(function(d){return d})
```

And instead of getting "100" "200" and "34" as text outputs, I get "attr1", "attr2", and "attr3". I would have expected the key function to return the values of `data`, but it's only returning the keys.

Any suggestions on how I can bind only *some* attributes of the `data` object, when I know those keys?

I know my use is a little "backwards"... I made a jsfiddle here to show the output: http://jsfiddle.net/ChwLM/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to filter change the data before setting it – http://jsfiddle.net/ChwLM/3/.

In d3, when you pass a function as the second argument, the following is how it gets called:

```
for (i = -1; ++i < m;) {
  keyValue = key.call(groupData, nodeData = groupData[i], i);
  if (node = nodeByKeyValue.get(keyValue)) {
    updateNodes[i] = node;
    node.__data__ = nodeData;
  } else if (!dataByKeyValue.has(keyValue)) { // no duplicate data key
    enterNodes[i] = d3_selection_dataNode(nodeData);
  }
  dataByKeyValue.set(keyValue, nodeData);
  nodeByKeyValue.remove(keyValue);
}
```

`groupData` is `['attr1', 'attr3', 'attr20']`. What you are changing with your function is the key of the data, not the value. With this – `nodeData = groupData[i]` – the value is getting set before you can change it. Here's the relevant piece from the fiddle above:

```
keys = ['attr1', 'attr3', 'attr20'];
filtered = [];
for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; ++i) {
    filtered.push(data[keys[i]]);
}
```

And then you can pass `filtered` in to `.data`.